# Proof by Induction: Summation

Tags: proof-verification

[Hello. I am just beginning proof by induction. Would anyone be willing to see if I am grasping this correctly?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHa9u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct, but just with some typos. It should be $6(k+1)^2$ instead of $6+(k+1)$ on your third last line, and you missed a right bracket on your last line of proof. Also, usually it's easier to edit and look for us if you can type it in mathjax.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for the help. Is mathjax free to download, and if so, where do I find it?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes it does, thanks!